# How to animate Markercluster Icons

Tags: google-maps, jquery, markers, animation

I am using Jquery Google Map V3 with markerclusterplus. I want to animate a cluster icon when hover the icon. My Clusterhover event code is,

```
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markersarray,mcOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(mc, "mouseover", function (c) {
          console.log(this);
          $(this).effect( 'bounce', { times: 3 }, 'slow');
          //$("div.cluster").effect( 'bounce', { times: 3 }, 'slow');

    });
```

But I am facing following error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).effect is not a function(anonymous function) @ groupmap.html:309S.trigger @ main.js:20(anonymous function) @ markercluster.js:186
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the `c` variable in my browser's developer tools, I found that the actual HTML element you want your effect on is `c.clusterIcon_.div_`. Your `google.maps.event.addListener` function should then look like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, "mouseover", function (c) {
    $(c.clusterIcon_.div_).effect( 'bounce', { times: 3 }, 'slow');
});
```

Your error message indicates that you have not added the jQuery UI javascript files in your code, or you placed them too far at the bottom. It should be included *before* you call any jQuery UI functions like `effect`.

Here is a working JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k65qkhbL/1/